# Unable to send a message from one emulator to another in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to send a message from one avd to another. But after updating my Android Studio, I can't. As a phone number I use the port number of the destination emulator window(i.e. I send from 5556 window to 5554), but the emulator doesn't receive the message. I use Android studio 2.1.3. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtCXW.png).